# Won't let me download apps on the app store help

Tags: iphone, ios

It says "verification required before you make a purchase you must tap continue to verify your payment" but the apps are free i've tried taking off the card too but that wont work

Answer (score 0):

It may be confusing but even when the app is free you are asked (should be asked) for your Apple ID and password to proceed. Provide your credentials (no matter if the app you're going to download is free) and it really should work...

Answer (score 0):

If you already associated a credit card to your Apple ID you will need to verify certain data (usually the CVC, but maybe other data as Phone number, ZIP code, etc.) before being allowed to use the account, **even** if the app in question is free. It does not mean it will charge you, it just wants to be sure that is you, and that your payment information is correct.